# What’s a word called that indicates the sex of the user?

Tags: meaning

Whilst not germane to English, some languages use different words, like pronouns, to differentiate the sexes. For example, in Thai the pronoun “I” as in I Go for a male speaker is “Pom” and for a female “Chan”.

Comment: Are you asking for a hypernym for masculine and feminine pronouns?

Comment: Thank you for your question, Paulie.  It is interesting, but needs a little more detail.  For example, on ELU a question should include an indication of what steps you have taken to find out for yourself (by researching on a website or in a grammar or dictionary).  There is a simple answer for English.  The answer is that in English only one set of pronouns is differentiated by gender:  the third person singular ('he' 'she' 'it').  The first person singular and plural ('I' and 'we') and third person plural ('they') have no gender inflection.  The second person has only 'you'.

Answer (score 3):

We simply say such words are *gender-specific*.

> **gender-specific** adjective
>
> ...
>
> 1.1 Denoting a word or expression that refers to one gender only.
>
> ‘the use of gender-specific terms such as 'man' and 'brothers'’

[[ODO](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/gender-specific)]

Comment: This certainly seems to be a common usage in grammar/language-learning texts (English has gender-specific pronouns in the 3rd person: he, she, etc), and of course "gender-neutral" is the opposite.